# how to assign an event object to a global variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript

This method is not working....
The pObject is global but not being assigned to the evt object. How can I get this to work?

```
        <script>
                var pEle = document.getElementById("pElement");
                var pObject;    
                pEle.addEventListener("click", function(evt)
                {
                    pOjbect = evt; 
                    console.log(typeof pObject);  // undefined
                }, false);
       </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get this to work?

By fixing your spelling.

Do

```
pObject = evt;
```

instead of

```
pOjbect = evt;
```

You might want to start the code in every `<script>` element with `'use strict';`, then JavaScript will complain about undeclared variables.

Demo:

```html
<button id="pElement">Click me</button>

<script>
  'use strict';
  var pEle = document.getElementById("pElement");
  var pObject;
  pEle.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    pOjbect = evt;
    console.log(typeof pObject); // undefined
  }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: This is why strict mode is your friend. (I just wish it threw errors at compile time, like Perl, instead of waiting until runtime.)